# CSS counter-reset

Tags: css

I'm having trouble understanding why some counters work, and some do not. In the following HTML, the goal is that the cnt3 style is used to create a table of contents list using <h3>, that matches subsequent <h2> headers. And I want the numbering in the table of contents to match the numbering of the <h2> headers.  And I'm trying to use CSS counters to do it, and mostly it is working, but it seems my h3s counter for the table of contents, is either not getting incremented, or is getting reset too often, but I can't tell why, nor have I figured out how to debug this... Mozilla Firebug seems to tell me the counter-increment is getting used in the right places, but it seems to have no effect on the numbering.  Obviously, this is a stripped example, just to demonstrate the problem, which appeared in a much larger document.

**HTML**

```
<h1>H1 Title</h1>
<h2>H2 Title</h2>
<h3 class="cnt3">H3 1</h3>
<h3 class="cnt3">H3 2</h3>
<h3 class="cnt3">H3 3</h3>
<h2 class="cnt">H2 Title 2</h2>
<h3 class="top">H3 4</h3>
<h3 class="top">H3 5</h3>
<h3 class="top">H3 6</h3>
<h2 class="cnt">H2 Title 3</h2>
```

**CSS**

```css
h1 {
    counter-reset: h2s;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20pt;
    counter-reset: h3s;
    counter-reset: h3t;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 16pt;
    counter-reset: h4t;
}
h2.cnt:before {
    content: 'Section ' counter( h2s, decimal ) ': ';
    counter-increment: h2s;
}
h3.cnt3:before {
    content: 'Section ' counter( h3s, decimal ) ': ';
    counter-increment: h3s;
}
h3.top:before {
    font-size: 16pt;
    content: counter( h2s, decimal ) '.' counter( h3t, decimal ) ': ';
    counter-increment: h3t;
}
h4 { font-size: 13pt; }
h4.top:before {
    font-size: 16pt;
    content: counter( h2s, decimal ) '.' counter( h3t, decimal ) '.' counter( h4t, decimal ) ': ';
    counter-increment: h4t;
}
```

Problem happens in both Firefox and Chrome, so I suppose it is my code rather than the same bug in both browsers!

Comment: What the hell is counter reset for? Isn't it just for lists. I would use HTML 5. Sections reset your outline for you.

Comment: @Leeish [counters are not just for list items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters)

Comment: @Leeish, counter-reset is supposed to start a counter over again. Counters can be used to count anything, it seems, if you get the styles right.  I have mine mostly right, but not quite. I guess I'm unaware of the HTML 5 feature you are referring to? Is it called Sections?  Off to Google...

Comment: @Leeish Hmm. I'm talking about creating a table of contents that contains an outline of the topics in the document, which will actually appear in the document. The HTML 5 section is talking about organizing a web page for a tool called an outliner, but that tool wouldn't provide an outline that is visible in the document (as far as I can read about it quickly).

Comment: I guess I am ignorant as to topic outlining/table of contents at the meta level in CSS. I might have to do some reading. What is the benefit of such a thing?

Comment: @Leeish The benefit of using a CSS counter to number things, is that when you insert or delete an item, you don't have to adjust the numbers of all the subsequent items.  In this case, where I am using one set of numbers for the table of contents and another set for the actual document, I do need to be careful to insert/delete the same text in both places... but won't have to adjust the numbering in either place, if I figure out why my one counter isn't counting!

Comment: @steveax - curious why you separated the HTML and CSS, that makes it harder for someone to paste into a file and test in their browser...

Comment: OK, I stumbled upon _what_ the problem is, but don't understand _why_. In the CSS for h2, I have 2 counter-reset properties; if I combine them as "counter-reset: h3s h3t;" then it works, but separately it does not. So I still need to know why....

Comment: @Leeish: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters

Comment: @Victoria usually, folks test things like this on jsfiddle.net or similar (which has separate fields for HTML, CSS and JS). It's expedient to go ahead and create a fiddle for your question too.  Also, separating them gets you proper syntax coloring for each here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @steveax thanks for the explanation. Never heard of jsfiddle.net. Syntax coloring is a good reason, all by itself.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks. But can you show me a practical use for this counters/chapters thing. I've been doing this a while and apparently never used this feature.

Comment: @leeish I consider my use quite practical, but it might not be a typical web site sort of use... I actually use HTML to make documents of the sort most people would use Word for, and then they can be published on the web, or converted to PDF with appropriate tools. I've usually done section numbering by hand, but this time I tried to figure out how to use the CSS counters to make a form of autonumbering. Now that I learned the trick of keeping all the counter resets in one property definition, it is working quite well as an autonumbering technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the method as it should be used.

Cascade rules runs also for this property.
So here ....

```
h2 {
    font-size: 20pt;
    counter-reset: h3s;
    counter-reset: h3t;
    }
```

your second definition of the property overrides the previous.

When you reset 2 counters for the same element **they should be specified together** as I show below

Your h2 rules should look as follows

```
h2 {
    font-size: 20pt;
    counter-reset: h3s h3t;
}
```

Here you have a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/avetod/1/edit) working fine

Comment: Cascade rules, eh?  OK, I'll study how that affects things, and try to understand how it produced the symptom.

Comment: Ah, got it... the rules say that only the second item is reset... but it seemed like the first item was getting reset too often... each item came out number 1!  But that was because there was no counter of that name defined at all, since this counter-reset was scoped out of existence... therefore each h3 with style=cnt3 wound up defining a new instance of h3s, which was implicitly reset to 0, explicitly incremented to 1 and used, and then vanished. Thanks for all the help.